# Why is the image not displayed after button click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I faced a problem so I created an example with styles that make no sense in this context : [link](https://jsfiddle.net/demidyuk/ptm2sfrw/). The question is why clicking on the first button does not lead to the image being displayed while all works in the second case? The difference just in css property which should have the same behaviour.

```
transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
```

```
transform: translateY(0px);
```

So I need just an explanation (not how to fix it) why it works like this.
I tested it in Chrome, my version is 88.0.4324.96.
The most interesting thing is that after clicking the button, the image can appear after resizing the window.
Thanks for your answers!

I created [one more example](https://jsfiddle.net/demidyuk/1x45pksj/1/)  where changed the width and made the transform the same, the result almost as previous.

Comment: If you apply `translate3d(0px, 0px, 1)` it works, might be an issue with the `z` property. Funny enough, if you add `position: relative` to `.image` it works.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a bug in Chrome. It works in firefox, and resizing the page or toggling on-off some css properties fixes the problem.

I think it is related to a difference between hardware and software rendering. In software rendering (translateY) the image load causes a repaint, but in hardware rendering (translate3d) does not.

Comment: I added one more example where there is no difference apart from width: https://jsfiddle.net/demidyuk/1x45pksj/1/

Answer (score 0):

This is a Chrome issue, so I already reported